# javax.naming.NoInitialContextException when running solr start (SOLR 8) in standalone local enviroment

Tags: java, solr, configuration, jetty, solr8

I,m having a problem when I try to start solr in my local computer. I'm using Windows 10.
When I execute .\solr.cmd start in solrFolder/bin I retrieve the exception:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:218)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.start(Main.java:491)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.main(Main.java:77)
Caused by: java.security.PrivilegedActionException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:1873)
        ... 7 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$JettyXmlConfiguration.invokeConstructor(XmlConfiguration.java:768)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$JettyXmlConfiguration.construct(XmlConfiguration.java:1055)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$JettyXmlConfiguration.newObj(XmlConfiguration.java:1027)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$JettyXmlConfiguration.configure(XmlConfiguration.java:537)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$JettyXmlConfiguration.configure(XmlConfiguration.java:473)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.configure(XmlConfiguration.java:399)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.WebAppProvider.createContextHandler(WebAppProvider.java:299)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.App.getContextHandler(App.java:99)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.bindings.StandardDeployer.processBinding(StandardDeployer.java:39)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.AppLifeCycle.runBindings(AppLifeCycle.java:188)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.requestAppGoal(DeploymentManager.java:513)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.addApp(DeploymentManager.java:154)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:173)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.WebAppProvider.fileAdded(WebAppProvider.java:447)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider$1.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:66)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportAddition(Scanner.java:784)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportDifferences(Scanner.java:753)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.scan(Scanner.java:641)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.doStart(Scanner.java:540)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:72)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.doStart(ScanningAppProvider.java:146)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:72)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.startAppProvider(DeploymentManager.java:599)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.doStart(DeploymentManager.java:249)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:72)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:169)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:407)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:117)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:97)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:371)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:72)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.lambda$main$1(XmlConfiguration.java:1924)
        ... 9 more
Caused by: javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial
        at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(Unknown Source)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(Unknown Source)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.getURLOrDefaultInitCtx(Unknown Source)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.getNameParser(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.plus.jndi.NamingEntry.save(NamingEntry.java:191)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.plus.jndi.Resource.<init>(Resource.java:32)
        ... 45 more
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:218)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.start(Main.java:491)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.main(Main.java:77)
Caused by: java.security.PrivilegedActionException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:1873)
        ... 7 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$JettyXmlConfiguration.invokeConstructor(XmlConfiguration.java:768)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$JettyXmlConfiguration.construct(XmlConfiguration.java:1055)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$JettyXmlConfiguration.newObj(XmlConfiguration.java:1027)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$JettyXmlConfiguration.configure(XmlConfiguration.java:537)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$JettyXmlConfiguration.configure(XmlConfiguration.java:473)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.configure(XmlConfiguration.java:399)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.WebAppProvider.createContextHandler(WebAppProvider.java:299)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.App.getContextHandler(App.java:99)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.bindings.StandardDeployer.processBinding(StandardDeployer.java:39)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.AppLifeCycle.runBindings(AppLifeCycle.java:188)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.requestAppGoal(DeploymentManager.java:513)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.addApp(DeploymentManager.java:154)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:173)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.WebAppProvider.fileAdded(WebAppProvider.java:447)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider$1.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:66)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportAddition(Scanner.java:784)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportDifferences(Scanner.java:753)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.scan(Scanner.java:641)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.doStart(Scanner.java:540)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:72)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.doStart(ScanningAppProvider.java:146)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:72)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.startAppProvider(DeploymentManager.java:599)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.doStart(DeploymentManager.java:249)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:72)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:169)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:407)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:117)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:97)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:371)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:72)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.lambda$main$1(XmlConfiguration.java:1924)
        ... 9 more
Caused by: javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial
        at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(Unknown Source)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(Unknown Source)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.getURLOrDefaultInitCtx(Unknown Source)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.getNameParser(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.plus.jndi.NamingEntry.save(NamingEntry.java:191)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.plus.jndi.Resource.<init>(Resource.java:32)
        ... 45 more
```

Im using solr 8.7.0, and this exception probably happends beacuas I'm trying to configure via JNDI the datasource used in my DIH.

The definition of my datasource in the solrconfig.xml:
`<dataSource name="candidatos_ds_read" jndiName="jdbc/PeopleNet" type="JdbcDataSource" readOnly="true" transactionIsolation="TRANSACTION_READ_UNCOMMITTED" />`

The property definition in solr-jetty-context.xml at solrFolder\server\context inside Configure tag:

```
    <New id="dataSource" class="org.eclipse.jetty.plus.jndi.Resource">
        
        <Arg>jdbc/PeopleNet</Arg>
        <Arg>
            <New class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
                <Set name="driverClassName">com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</Set>
                <Set name="url">jdbc:sqlserver://AXDESSQL2.CENTRAL.MINE.GRP:11433;databaseName=Dadatbase</Set>
                <Set name="username">user</Set>
                <Set name="password">password</Set>
                <Set name="maxActive">3</Set>
                <Set name="maxIdle">30</Set><
                <Set name="maxWait">10000</Set>
            </New>
        </Arg>
    </New>
```

And I've added in solrfolder\server\solr-webapp\webapp\WEB-INF\web.xml the resource ref inside web-app tag:

```
  <resource-ref>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/PeopleNet</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
  </resource-ref>
```

Solr documentation doesn't help whit this kind of configurations, so anyone can help me?
regards

Answer (score 0):

The DataSource definition is missing the scope reference.

You mention `solrFolder\server\context` and `solr-jetty-context.xml` but you don't give the rest of the context XML, so the exact syntax is unknown.

But it would look like this (roughly)

```xml
    <New id="dataSource" class="org.eclipse.jetty.plus.jndi.Resource">
        <Arg><!-- the scope reference here, either jvm, server, or webappcontext --><Arg>
        <Arg>jdbc/PeopleNet</Arg>
        <Arg>
            <New class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
                <Set name="driverClassName">com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</Set>
                <Set name="url">jdbc:sqlserver://AXDESSQL2.CENTRAL.MINE.GRP:11433;databaseName=Dadatbase</Set>
                <Set name="username">user</Set>
                <Set name="password">password</Set>
                <Set name="maxActive">3</Set>
                <Set name="maxIdle">30</Set><
                <Set name="maxWait">10000</Set>
            </New>
        </Arg>
    </New>
```

See https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/jetty-9/index.html#jndi-quick-setup and the section titled
"Scope of Resource Names" for examples of the different types of scopes you can use.